# Delphi 11 AV when starting new vcl project

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

[image: av when - file-new- windows vcl application vcl]

Hi - I cannot start another application by the usual method
file-new- windows vcl application vcl
I get an AV as shown.
If I open an old project - all is OK - otherwise I get the problem below:
I have searched for hours regarding this. Can anyone help?
Thanks,
Chris

Thanks for your comments.
I havent added any other components since this problem started.
Here are the details, but I cant really understand them!
The last image is presumably the failure point in coreide280.bpl, but what does the 'move designer' mean?
[image: details]

[image]

Comment: Clearly a bug in the IDE. It is accessing a nil pointer somewhere. Have you filed a bug report with Embarcadero? Have you tried reinstalling the IDE?

Comment: Are you using any third-party extensions or IDE add-ons?

Comment: I have not kept up my subscription to Embarcadero as I cant afford it.

Comment: I have written a few small windows apps from scratch without problems. I havent added any new components/extensions or updates. This has just happened. I will re-install if necessary, but its going to be a hassle! I'm sure that the sentence 'This form is being designed....' has something to do with all this. I have checked the directory structure as far as I can, but this is a bit of a nightmare!

Comment: It could be that some files are corrupted on your project's level.

Comment: Thanks. What folders do you suggest? I have two machines with D11 (the other one has another problem to do with android creation, but I could copy some folders over? Is that a good idea - they are both have  the same updates.